# If $a$ divides $(n-1)!$, $b$ divides $n!$ and $ab < n!$, does it follow that $ab$ divides $n!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I haven't been able to come up with a counterexample so far.

Comment: I would really like to know how much time you spent in your fruitless search for counterexamples, and especially, what kind of examples you were trying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a=b=2$. $a$ divides $2!$, $b$ divides $3!$, but their product $4$ does not divide $3!$

Answer (score 3):

In general, this does not hold for any $n$ except for $n \leq 2$.

You can check that the result holds for $n \leq 2$ by just considering all of the possible values of $n$, $a$ and $b$. (There aren't that many)

If $n \geq 3$, then by Bertrand's Postulate, there is a prime $p$ strictly between $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$.

Take $a=b=p$. Then since $p \leq n-1$, we have that $a \mid (n-1)!$ and $b \mid n!$.

Further, we have that $ab \leq (n-1)^2 < n!$. (Since $n! \geq n(n-1) > (n-1)^2$)

Thus $ab < n!$. But $p$ only divides $n!$ once (i.e. $p^2$ does not divide $n!$), and so $ab$ does not divide $n!$.

As a concrete example, lets take $n=42$. Then $23$ is a prime strictly between $21$ and $42$. Then my claim is that $23 \mid 41!$ and $23 \mid 42!$, and $23^2 \not\mid 42!$ even though $23^2 < 42!$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n=4$, $a=3$, $b=6$. Then you have a counterexample, which shows that the claim is invalid.